# How to pass a data from a component to other route in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have the following component structure:-

```
MainLayout ------------------> Pages
 |                              |
 |---> MyGroupList              |
 |      |                       |
 |      |---> MyGroup           |--> MyGroupPage
 |             |                     ^  
 |             |--onClick -----------| 
 |
 |
 |----> MyInputBox
```

`MainLayout` has a page `MyGroupPage` which needs to display a list of fetched messages in a group based on the `MyGroup` that is being clicked. But I also want to add new messages in a particular group. To do that I have `MyInputBox`.

Currently the list of groups and messages in a group are being fetched by the `MainLayout`, I am sending the group list to the `MyGroupList` as props. I am emitting an event with the current group as an argument when I click on `MyGroup` and I bubble that event all the way to the `MainLayout` .

```
<!--In MyGroup Component-->

 <q-item
    clickable
    v-ripple
    class="q-pa-md"
    @click="$emit('changedGroup', group)"
    :to="{ name: 'MyGroupPage', params: { group: group.id } }"
  >
```

```
<!-- In MyGroupList Component-->

<q-list bordered>
    <MyGroup
      v-for="group in groups"
      :key="group.id"
      :group="group"
      @changed-group="(currGroup) => $emit('changedGroup', currGroup)"
    />
  </q-list>
```

There I fetch the messages of that group.

I also use `MyInputBox` to ask for input and send that message as a event back to the `MainLayout`. There I am adding that new message in the list of the fetched messages.

```
<!-- In MainLayout Component -->

<template> 
  <q-layout view="lHr lpr lFr">
   <MyGroupList :groups="groups" @changed-group="changeGroupHandler"/>
      <q-page-container>
        <router-view />
      </q-page-container>
    <MyInputBox @add-chat="addChat"/>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script setup>
const groups = ref([]);

fetchGroups()
  .then((fetchedGroups) => (groups.value = fetchedGroups))

const messages = ref([]);

const changeGroupHandler = (currGroup) => {
  fetchMessages(currGroup) 
    .then((fetchedMessages) => (messages.value = fetchedMessages))
}

const addMessage = mess => messages.value.push(mess);
</script>
```

But I am not able to figure out how to send that list of messages to the `MyGroupPage`.
Since the `MyGroupPage` page is being switched when `MyGroup` is clicked, Do I need to pass the updated list of messages from `MainLayout` again to `MyGroup` and send it as a route param to the `MyGroupPage`.

I wanted to know how to do that and If what I am doing is a good practice or not?

Earlier Instead of emitting events, I was storing the current group in a composable as a global state. How does that compare to this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, this seems to be a good case for using a store like Vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store.

It offers a structure for what you are trying to achieve by sharing a state with all the components.

Since it seems tightly coupled, it will probably be easier than trying to communicate between pages in a way that will probably be hard to maintain.

edit: I found since this answer that Vuex is not the recommended solution anymore.

It is now Pinia that is recommended. For anyone wanting to add a store to a Vue.js application, it might be a better choice.

https://pinia.vuejs.org/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I feel that this might just work. I will definitely check it out.

Comment: I don't now if you got a notification on my edit @CeNiEi but you might want to check out Pinia if you have not already made vows to Vuex. It was announced recently.

Comment: Actually I already had opted for pinia instead of veux. I am using quasar framework and there too, Pinia was recommended over Veux

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just use the VueX store.
Keeping your data there would be the cleanest solution.

But if you absolutely have to use a router, you could pass your data as route params:

```
// Routing to other page  
this.$router.push({  
    name: 'Name_Of_The_Other_Page',  
    params: { myData: 'Your data here' }  
});

// Accessing params on the other page  
let myData = this.$route.params.myData
```